# Can Linux use a CPU core as a micro-controller?

Tags: kernel, raspberry-pi, real-time

Correct me if I'm wrong:

As far as I searched around the web, the main difference between a micro-controller (like Arduino) and a SBC (like Raspberry Pi) is that the micro-controller is atomic which means it runs your code line by line and does nothing else, no delay. But a SBC (RPi for example) runs an OS, and the OS is not atomic, which means it will schedule your code for running, because the OS has to do other works too, your code may run with a delay, depending on how busy the OS is.

Therefore, for some projects like a flight controller for example, we should use a micro-controller so the drone would react to our commands and sensors' data immediately without any delay.

There are some boards like the BeagleBone that have a CPU capable of running an OS, and one or more micro-controllers capable of doing something atomic. which means you get both worlds with one board.

Now here's my question:

On a multi-core CPU that is running a Linux OS, can we tell the Linux kernel to reserve one core for only one process? Say I have a Python program that controls a drone on a Raspberry Pi, can I tell Linux to use three of four cores for itself and use one core just for my flight controller program? Am I making any sense?

I am aware of Linux job priority and some real-time Linux kernels, but I haven't looked into those options in detail. I would appreciate any guidance regarding this topic, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that what I had in my mind is kind of possible (but it's complex).

We have two ways to tell Linux to exclude one or more CPUs from its normal process scheduling.

1. The `isolcpus` boot option ([documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt))
2. The Linux specific `cpusets` ([documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/cpusets.txt))

After that, a program can tell Linux that it wants to be run on that CPU with the following system call:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>

int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid, size_t len, cpu_set_t *set);
```

This way that specific CPU (or CPUs) will be just for that process (or processes).

Answer (score 1):

A microcontroller is in principle not different from a general purpose CPU. A microcontroller also handles interrupts, which preempts the flow of code, so you can not count on precise cycle timing. You can also have a scheduler on a microcontroller, this depends on the operating system. The Programmable Realtime Unit (PRU) on the Beaglebone you mentioned is a very specialized processor designed for cycle-precise operation, not a "normal" microcontroller.

You may be able to pin a process to a specific CPU core, but this does not mean that process gets exclusive access to the core. What you really want on Linux is real-time scheduling. You may be successful by just using a higher priority for your control process.